# Parsing notes saved in text file to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a script that allows me to open and view the general notes I save at work and studies. I have this particular function, and I am afraid it will become overwhelming. How should I approach this?

The purpose of the function is to parse summary information into a JSON and record stats like last modified, times viewed, date created, etc. So I can organise the notes with this information and ignore the file contents.

```
def note_component(note_lines):
    """ Creates the new note data structure.
        Here is where one would add more note information.

    :param list[str] note: containing a single note.
    :return: the dict note element.
    """
    sections = get_sections(note_lines)
    contents = get_contents(note_lines)

    # This loops through multiple notes
    note_component = {}
    for heading, content in zip(sections, contents):
        heading = save_text(heading, content)

        note_component[heading] = {
            'timestamp': None,
        }

        note_component[heading]['timestamp'] = 'now'

        description = note_description(content)
        if description:
            note_component[heading]['description'] = description

        tags = note_tags(content)
        if tags:
            note_component[heading]['tags'] = tags

    return note_component
```

A typical note contains markup that allows the rest of the script to identify which parts belong where. Here is a typical note:

```
# the_title
==============
:Describe the note to me

Contents.
 - further point


On a final note!

{tag} {code} {review}
==============
```

So this note will be passed into the `note_component` function in the form of a list of strings:

```
note_lines = [
    '# the_title',
    '==============',
    ':Describe the note to me',
    '',
    'Contents.',
    ' - further point',
    '',
    '',
    'On a final note!',
    '',
    '{tag} {code} {review}',
    '=============='
]
```

Here are the functions used in `note_component`:

```
def get_sections(note):
    # Section parsing needs improvement (regex)
    _sections = [line[2:] for line in note if line[:2] == '# ']
    return _sections


def note_description(content):
    # Needs to return multiple descriptions (sectioning)
    description = content[1]
    if description and description[0] == ':':
        return description
    return None


def save_text(heading, content):
    """ This saves the note as a text file.
    :param heading: (string) the heading of the note used as filename.
    :param content: (list) containing the lines of the note.
    """
    heading = unique_note(heading)

    text_string = '\n# {heading}\n'.format(heading=heading)
    text_string += '\n'.join(content)

    name_note = NOTES.format(
        note_name=heading
    )

    with open(name_note, 'w') as save_txt:
        save_txt.write(text_string)

    return heading


def unique_note(heading):
    saved_notes = [filename for filename in os.listdir(NOTE_DIR)]

    suffix = 0
    if '{heading}.txt'.format(heading=heading) in saved_notes:
        while '{}_{}.txt'.format(heading, str(suffix)) in saved_notes:
            suffix += 1

        new_name = '{}_{}'.format(heading, str(suffix))
        heading = new_name

    return heading


def note_tags(contents):
    tag_line = contents[-2]

    if tag_line and '{' in tag_line:
        tags = [tag[1:-1] for tag in tag_line.split(' ') if tag]
        return tags
    return None


def pairwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)


def get_contents(note):
    content_index = [
        index
        for index, line
        in enumerate(note)
        if line[:2] == '=='
    ]

    content_list = []
    indexes = pairwise(content_index)

    for start, end in indexes:
        content = note[start:end+1]
        content_list.append(content)

    return content_list
```

Please excuse the missing doc-strings.

My biggest concerns are, how should I approach this function to make it easy to test, and easy to expand information stored `note_component` with out losing readability?

I think I also need to improve my distinctions in variable names.

Comment: Do I need to add more information to this question?

Comment: Honestly your code is missing quite a lot of context, it's answerable now, but it mostly comes down to, 'we don't know what 90% of your code is doing, and so we can't change that, in the last 10% there's one minor change you could possibly make'. If you include the other 90%, then we'll be able to give more concrete answers on the 10% and 90% too.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Question updated.

Comment: If you have docstrings, please include them. Otherwise, the lack of docstrings is fair criticism for a review.

Comment: Fair, that is how it is.